# How to keep entire group if at least one row in the group meets the criteria in R?

Tags: r

So I want to drop any row that has less than 100 in assets(at) or less than 100 in sales(sale) or if there is a missing value for emp, sale, or at.

Afterward, I want to find the average employment (emp) per firm in the US (loc == "USA) that was listed at any time over the years (fyear) 2010 to 2013 inclusive.

As long as a firm is listed in that time period at all, I want to include it in the calculation. How can I keep the entire group even if one row has fyear between 2010 to 2013?

The unique firm identifier is gvkey.

This is what I have now:

```
companies_q_three <- companies %>%
  filter(at >= 100 | sale >= 100) %>%
  filter(!is.na(sale), !is.na(emp), !is.na(at)) %>%
  filter (loc == "USA") %>%
  group_by(gvkey) %>%
  filter(fyear >= 2010 & fyear <= 2013) %>%
  summarise(companies_q_three = mean(emp, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Comment: can you provide some data? `dput(head(your_data))`?

Comment: You could `group`, use `mutate` to make a "keep" variable based on calculations about the group, then `filter` on and drop "keep". Without a reproducible example (with data), we can only make suggestions

Comment: Here's an example using data we have:  `library(dplyr);
starwars %>%  
  group_by(homeworld) %>%
  mutate(Luke_count = sum(name %>% str_detect("Luke"))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(Luke_count >= 1)`

Comment: Or you could use a two step process: `include_these_homeworlds <- starwars %>%
  count(homeworld, wt = sum(name %>% str_detect("Luke")), name = "Luke_count") %>%
  filter(Luke_count >= 1); 

starwars %>% right_join(include_these_homeworlds)`